# Mean-centerinfg for logit values?

Tags: probability, logistic, mean, proportion, centering

I have a question regarding the logistic growth model. Can proportion values that have been converted into logit be mean-centered? When we calculate the actual difference value between two proportion values (0.8 and 0.6, which is the mean value of a certain variable), we get 0.2. However, when we first convert these two values into the two logit values, and then subtract each other(0.981), then again inversely transform the difference value (0.981) into a proportion value, we get 0.727, which is different from 0.2 by 0.527. Despite this difference, I am curious if mean-centering can be still applied to logit values. I would appreciate it if you can help with this question.

Additional info: I am analyzing the relationship between pass rates and time for mathematics, physics, and chemistry exams over a 2-year period. The study includes students from groups A, B, and C. Mathematics is crucial to both physics and chemistry, making math scores particularly important. One of my research aims is to determine whether there is a group difference in the pass rate differences for mathematics and physics (difference  between  Math-Physics) between group A and (B or C) . To achieve this, I first converted probability values to logit values. Since pass rates differ among the three subjects across the various groups, I plan to calculate the mean values for each subject among all students and then perform mean-centering for analysis. However, I am unsure if it is appropriate to mean-center the logit values obtained from the probability values, hence my inquiry.

Comment: Average is invariant to linearly transformations only. Therefore, it is not surprising that the two operations you mentioned do not agree. May I ask you why you want to center the logit observations?

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I included additional info above. I would greatly appreciate any comments that you can provide.